# Apply "Has a" method and remove inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class A {
    class B {
        public:
        void doSomething();
    };
    class C : public B {};
    class D : public B {};

};
        
// In B.hpp file
class hello {
    class hi {};
    class world : public hi, public C {};
};
    
// In main.cpp file    
int main() {
    world my_world;
    my_world.doSomething();
}
```

In this code, I want to remove the inheritance between class B and class C. When I instantiate class world, I should still be able to access doSomthing() method from class world.
Is there a way to implement "Has a" method which is as per my understanding a pointer to the base class?

Comment: Is this just a thought experiment? This is an *extremely* complex class inheritance hierarchy. What could you possibly be modeling with this? It's very hard for me to follow even with these overly simplified names and with most of the methods removed.

Comment: I am trying to understand "is a" and "has a". I understand "is a" means inheritance but I don't know how to implement "has a" in this same code. @CodyGray Which part you did not understand? How would you simplify this?

Comment: @varconst If you're trying to grasp the concepts *(in the context of the Cpp)*, I would advise you to not to go from the language to some situation, but in other direction - finding a real world relation of *is a*/*has a* and then implementing them in the code.

Comment: "Has a" means composition. I do understand the code from a technical point of view, but it's difficult for me to wrap my mind fully around it. I'd simplify it by taking a step back and figuring out what I really trying to model here, and then coming up with a simpler model. Also note that your current code is *incorrect*. You need to make these members `public`, for one thing (class members default to being `private`), and you are also missing at least one semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in a comment, the code proposed in the question is incorrect as written. Class members default to being `private`, so you need to explicitly mark them as `public` if you want to be able to access them from outside of that class's context. Furthermore, you are missing some scope resolution operators and at least one semicolon. This is the corrected version of your current code. I've also added some code so that the `doSomething` function has an observable effect—i.e., so that it actually *does* something.

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    public:
        void doSomething() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; };
    };

    class C : public B
    { };

    class D : public B
    { };
};

class hello
{
public:
    class hi
    { };

    class world : public hi, public A::C
    { };
};

int main()
{
    hello::world my_world;
    my_world.doSomething();
}
```

Inheritance means "is-a", whereas *composition* means "has-a". What you have now (as shown above) is inheritance, so you're modeling "is-a". If you want "has-a" instead,  So, you want composition. Simply change `C` to have a member of type `B`:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    public:
        void doSomething() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; };
    };

    class C
    {
    public:
        B b;
    };

    class D : public B
    { };
};

class hello
{
public:
    class hi
    { };

    class world : public hi, public A::C
    { };
};

int main()
{
    hello::world my_world;
    my_world.b.doSomething();
}
```

Now, in this code, `C` **has a** `B`. It is named `b` (but you could name it whatever you wanted).

If you don't want to require that `doSomething` be accessed from the `b` member, then you'll need to write a wrapper function. That would even allow you to keep the `b` member `private`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    public:
        void doSomething() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; };
    };

    class C
    {
        B b;

    public:
        void doSomething() { b.doSomething(); }
    };

    class D : public B
    { };
};

class hello
{
public:
    class hi
    { };

    class world : public hi, public A::C
    { };
};

int main()
{
    hello::world my_world;
    my_world.doSomething();
}
```